# Emulador android acessa web service pelo navegador mas não acessa pelo APP

Tags: php, android-studio, api, aplicação-web

Bom dia, o que acontece é o seguinte meu emulador acessa meu web service pelo navegador, no endereço http://192.168.2.192/index.php, ele mostra o resultado da pagina, [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<?php
 $minha_info = "TESTE JSON";
    echo json_encode($minha_info);
?>
```

até onde eu entendi é para funcionar pois, na pagina tem uma informação, esse é o meu código no android studio

```html
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private Button button;
    private TextView textView;
    private TextInputEditText cep;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        cep = findViewById(R.id.cep);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                MyTask task = new MyTask();
                String numero = cep.getText().toString();
                String urlApi = "http://192.168.2.192/teste.php";
                task.execute(urlApi);

            }
        });

    }
    class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String stringurl = strings[0];
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = null;
            StringBuffer  buffer = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(stringurl);
                HttpURLConnection conexao = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                inputStream = conexao.getInputStream();
                inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                buffer = new StringBuffer();
                String linha = "";
                while ((linha = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    buffer.append(linha);
                }


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return buffer.toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            textView.setText(s);
        }
    }
}
```

porem, ele simplesmente crasha, e quando eu testo com web services externo ele funciona, porem somente com o meu web service local ele não funciona.

@EDIT
O problema foi resolvido acrescentando o networkacess

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

o aplicativo estava sem permissão para acessar a rede local

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro você precisa adicionar as permissões no seu AndroidManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Após esta configuração, use o ip: `10.0.2.2` para você conseguir acessar o seu localhost. Documentação: [aqui](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html)

Não esqueça de usar o protocolo http na chamada: `http://10.0.2.2/recurso`

Comment: Bom dia, eu consegui resolver, eu não tinha me atentado no debug, era exatamente a falta do ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, no debug tava aparecendo o erro de que não tinha permissão para acessar o  servidor, muito obrigado pela força.